# several questions about my CSS header menus

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

Im a complete newbie with CSS and im struggling to know what's the correct way to do things. There are so many examples online, but they all seem a bit different. I have some specific questions about my markup. but generally as well is it the right way?

My CSS feels bloated to me is it?
My overflow command is causing a scrollbar, but i don't know why
My top-menu has a large padding on the left, something to do with li + li i guess, but how do i get rid of it
Is my layout of Divs the best way to achieve what im trying to do. Using margin-top 70 to force down the second menu doesn't seem the best approach to me, isn't there something that would be like float bottom or valign bottom?

Any guidance to get me starting of on the right foot would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="logo">
    logo

    </div>
    <div class="top-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Lorum</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact us</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Countries
            <li>Vacancies</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Countries
            <li>Vacancies</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>


    .wrapper {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.logo {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.top-menu {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.top-menu > ul {
    line-style:  none;
}

.top-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.top-menu  li + li:before{
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-menu > ul {
    line-style:  none;
}

.main-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: aqua;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.top-menu {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.main-menu {
    font-family: arial;
    font-szie: 14px;
    background-color: crimson;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you don't close <li>Countries

Comment: I think your code is more than enough to achieve this..... no need to correct any thing it's good to go...

Comment: .wrapper class is duplicated with different width.

Comment: Why not create a working fiddle or pen from your code?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, some bad cut &  paste on my side with the duplicate classes. Will try fiddle in future!  anyone want to say i should be using ID and not class for most of these? doe sit really matter?

Answer (score 0):

.wrapper class is duplicated with different width. Many other class is duplicated.

Pay attention to code cleanup :)

In anyway the margin of ul in main-menu flowed out from the div, creating the scrollbar.
If you want, you can find this problem using inspect element in browser like in chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

```css
.logo {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: aqua;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.top-menu {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.top-menu::after {
    clear: both;
}

.main-menu {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: crimson;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.top-menu  li + li:before{
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-menu > ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.main-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="logo">
        logo
    </div>
    

    <div class="top-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Lorum</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Countries</li>
            <li>Vacancies</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Countries</li>
            <li>Vacancies</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3wurcpx/

Comment: thanks for the speedy response. I was using chrome for CSS live styling and notepad++ for HTML i think the code got a bit duplicated somewhere. Cleaned up now. I can see in the element inspector like you say that the bottom margin of main-menu is outside the wrapper causing the scroll bar. but i haven't added any bottom margin to main-menu. Is it some kind of browser default thing and i should use CSS resets?

Comment: do ytou have any  comments on this :  Using margin-top 70 to force down the second menu doesn't seem the best approach to me, isn't there something that would be like float bottom or valign bottom?   is that really teh best way to align bottom?

Comment: CSS reset is always a good choice because many html object have different rendering in different browser so, resetting to default choice value guarantees the webpages are displayed in the same way on all browsers.
Anyway div not have, in all browser, margin or padding by default unlike ul.
Probably the margin or padding you see come from ul.

Comment: Margin-top: 70 is not very elegant but sometimes be productive is more important and float bottom doesn't exist and valign bottom works only with inline-block element and is not ever simply.
To be elegant you have to create one div for every menu used by container  with fixed height or clear floating and inside you can work your menu like if are in a sandbox.

Comment: When you are more confident with CSS you can use framework like bootstrap  (http://getbootstrap.com/ )